# Why is .mainloop() and done() necessary in Wing, but not IDLE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In the first example, IDLE makes the window without .mainloop(), and in the second IDLE doesn't need done() to not crash. Why is this?

Example 1

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
btn = Button(tk, text ="click me", command=hello)
btn.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Example 2

```
from turtle import *
t = Pen()
t.forward(20)
done()
```

Comment: When you say IDLE, do you mean creating and running a .py file or just typing it into the interpreter?

Comment: I mean typing it in the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

The window is created in any case, add a pause after `btn.pack()` to see it even without `.mainloop()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import Tk, Button

root = Tk()
Button(root, text ="click me", command=root.destroy).pack()

input('Press Enter to exit..') # normally, you should use `root.mainloop()` here
```

IDLE itself is implemented using `tkinter` and therefore it calls `.mainloop()`.

`turtle` is also implemented using `tkinter`; `turtle.done()` calls `.mainloop()` internally.